# RunAs/Remote Desktop Windows Security - A Device attached to this device is not functioning correctly

Tags: windows, runas

Good Afternoon, never seen this one before in my years of working with Windows but im at a loss to try and find the solution to this one.

When users log on to their desktops as Non-Admin accounts, there are particular applications they need to run as different users due to the way some of the systems work.  A load of system policies where updated for security at group policy level however now something strange is happening when the user initiates a RunAs by holding the shift key down or if they attempt to remote desktop to another machine, the NLA Windows Security box that prompts for credentials takes 5/10 minutes to appear.

When the user hovers over the taskbar icon, then over the window without clicking the Windows Security box displays as full screen missing the username and password box but when you click on it nothing happens and just disappears.  Eventually after a few minutes the windows security box will appear and can log in as normal however the users jump into systems adhoc and cant be waiting for minutes at a time to put their credentials in which could cost a lot of user down time during the day.

I have tried looking at the security log but as you can imagine its filled with all sorts and trying to locate one specifically without knowing the issue is difficult at best.  Has anyone had this issue before that can point me in any direction.  I have to assume this is permission related on the devices trying to access something locally because when i log on to the devices with an account in the administrators group all these issues disappear and the windows security works as normal.  Also, if they click "Run as administrator" they get the UAC credential box so i don't believe this is UAC related as its working by design just anything with "Windows Security" prompts.  I should point out that whilst this is waiting - the File Explorer icon highlights under "Run As" like the explorer is waiting to do something.

OS - Windows 10 Pro
Acc - Domain Joined
Group policy enabled
Local Policy Disabled
Update: 21H2

Never seen this before but hoping one of you legends has!
Dev

[Full Screen Box - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNkCI.png)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this - although bizzare as it is...

It turns out it was McAfee Disk Encryption - there was a bug in the local FDE security provider causing it to hang every time it was accessed.

Update your McAfee FDE Client/Agent to the latest version